# Android Developer App Upload wants SDK <= 19

Tags: android, sdk, upload, google-play

i changes from Eclipse to Android Studio a few month ago.
Now i wanna publish an Upload, but after uploading my signed APK i get:

Upload failed
You have to use a SDK lower equals 19.

My gradle file looks like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.77'
}

configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion '19.1'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 18
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }


    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("XXX")
            storePassword "XXX"
            keyAlias "XXX"
            keyPassword "XXX"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        incremental true
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: That's a strange error alrite, but why not target API 19? It's been out for ages

Comment: Can we see the Android Manifest?

Comment: The Manifest...or just a part:

 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="de.hhu.zim"
  android:versionCode="44"
  android:versionName="1.11" >

  <!-- PERMISSION -->
  <!-- PERMISSION -->

  <uses-sdk
   android:maxSdkVersion="20"
   android:minSdkVersion="14"
   android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

Comment: I removed the <uses-sdk> part in my manifest, because i had the tooltip "...is overwritten by gradle file...". Now it works :)